# jointjs: I want to get the value of label from json text

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to get the value of text a "Label" and the type with JSON from this JSon text :

```
{
    "cells": [{
        "type": "devs.Model",
        "size": {
            "width": 40,
            "height": 40
        },
        "inPorts": [""],
        "outPorts": [""],
        "position": {
            "x": 168,
            "y": 99
        },
        "angle": 0,
        "id": "c7cf7b2d-3b54-4dd1-9cbf-7a37a72559fc",
        "z": 1,
        "attrs": {
            ".label": {
                "text": "aa",
                "ref-x": 0.4,
                "ref-y": 0.2
            },
            "rect": {
                "fill": "#2ECC71"
            },
            ".inPorts circle": {
                "fill": "#16A085",
                "magnet": "active",
                "type": "input"
            },
            ".outPorts circle": {
                "fill": "#E74C3C",
                "type": "output"
            },
            ".inPorts>.port0>.port-label": {
                "text": ""
            },
            ".inPorts>.port0>.port-body": {
                "port": {
                    "id": "in8",
                    "type": "in"
                }
            },
            ".inPorts>.port0": {
                "ref": ".body",
                "ref-y": 0.5
            },
            ".outPorts>.port0>.port-label": {
                "text": ""
            },
            ".outPorts>.port0>.port-body": {
                "port": {
                    "id": "out9",
                    "type": "out"
                }
            },
            ".outPorts>.port0": {
                "ref": ".body",
                "ref-y": 0.5,
                "ref-dx": 0
            }
        }
    }, {
        "type": "link",
        "source": {},
        "target": {},
        "id": "1e977b11-c003-4c22-ba48-c04994f63c79",
        "z": 2,
        "attrs": {}
    }]
}
```

For the label , I do : `document.write(jsonString.cells[0].attrs.label.text);`

and for the type : `(jsonString.cells[0].attrs.label.text);`

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(graph);
document.write(jsonString.cells[0].type);
```

Comment: `JSON.stringify` gives a string. Don't you mean `JSON.parse`?

Comment: no i need to get the value of all label from the json text of jointjs graph

Comment: your 2nd example doesn't work.

Comment: i wanna extract just the type and the label of graph from the json text

Comment: i get that but  you should try `.parse`.

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/javascript/how-to-access-json-object-in-javascript/

Comment: Anybody know answer for this question  I am willng to know

Comment: sorry but i dont get what you mean by .parse i extract the json text with stringify from the graph and then i wanna get extract just label field and type

Comment: Access `".label"` with `json.cells[0].attrs['.label']`. It will give you `{
                "text": "aa",
                "ref-x": 0.4,
                "ref-y": 0.2
            }`. Don't stringify it; it's pointless, since you would convert an accessible object into an inaccessible chain of characters.

Comment: @JeremyThille i already answered i mistakenly put . before attrs

Comment: What? Where? And you're not the OP, my comment was not addressed to you